# Cannot run a synchronous jQuery ajax request from a form submit within CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a js function that is called twice by actions on a form, once when a user enters text in a field via jQuery.change and the second time when the form is submitted.  When the form is submitted it calls the function to do an ajax request and then it should either stop or continue to submit the form based on the return value.  All I seem to be getting is the 'undefined' return value.

The function being called is this...

```
function cf_check_course_slug() {
    // check the slug name is unique
    var course_id = $('#Course_Id').val();
    var course_slug = $('#Slug').val();
    if(course_slug!='') {
        // call script via ajax and ensure it is not already assigned
        $.ajax({
            type:   "GET"
        ,   url:    "/courses/course_slug"
        ,   data:   { cid: course_id, slug: course_slug }
        ,   async:  false
        }).done(function(response) {
            // if we have a duplicate course slug then notify user
            if(response=='duplicate') {
                showErrorMessage('The SLUG created from the LINK NAME you have entered is already being used by another course, please edit the LINK NAME.')
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When the form is submitted, it fires the following code in the javascript...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // check we are in the correct module before firing this script
    if($('#course-form').length > 0) {

        // check the link name has created a unique slug
        $('#LinkName').change(function() {
            cf_check_course_slug();
        });


        // check the course record form prior to saving
        $('form').submit(function() {
            if(!cf_check_course_slug()) {
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

});
```

This cf_ function calls a controller within CI that performs a check on the database to check whether the slug is a duplicate and returns the string 'duplicate' if so.  It works perfectly if I update the link name and it does the check on .change.

I assume it has to be an issue with the async setting of the function as if I code it manually into the submit js, it works as expected - although, I'd rather keep this as dry as possible.

Any pointers would be great.

Update #1
Below is the following code that is in the controller and called from the javascript function.

```
function course_slug() {

        // first check this request has come via ajax
        if($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {

            $iCourse_Id = $this->input->get('cid', true);
            $sSlug = $this->input->get('slug', true);

            // load the model and data
            $this->load->model('Course_Model');
            $aCourses = $this->Course_Model->get_courses_by_category();

            // check each course and perform a check on the slug
            $output = '';
            foreach($aCourses as $aCourse) {
                // if we are dealing with an existing course, omit the Course_Id from the course dataset
                if($iCourse_Id && is_numeric($iCourse_Id)) {
                    if($aCourse['Course_Id']!=$iCourse_Id && $aCourse['Active']==1 && $aCourse['Slug']==$sSlug) {
                        $output = 'duplicate';
                    }
                } else {
                    // we are dealing with a new course, check through ALL courses in the dataset
                    if($aCourse['Slug']==$sSlug) {
                        $output = 'duplicate';
                    }
                }

            }

            // spit out the result
            $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($output));

        } else {
            // redirect to course homepage
            redirect('courses'); 
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your url section should be

```
url:    "< ?php echo site_url("/courses/course_slug"); ?>"
```

*you need to have the url helper loaded in order to use the site_url() or base_url() functions.

```
$this->load->helper("url");
```

instead of

```
url:    "/courses/course_slug"
```

Relative url's don't always work in codeigniter if you are using a standard htaccess, because codeigniter uses index.php to create the nice_url option and therefore your url should have been something like localhost/index.php/courses/course_slug and what you added there was localhost/courses/course_slug and that wouldn't work without the rewrite engine on.

Although it would be of more help as to why you are getting an undefined response if you could have posted the php script also.

Comment: Howdy Hun73r, I've added the php controller called by the ajax in the original post.  I changed the url value to the full url path of the controller but still no joy.